# In-App Purchase Issue: Works with Test User, Not with External User in Open Testing: Android

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, in-app-billing

I'm currently testing an Android application in an open testing phase, and I've encountered a perplexing issue with in-app purchases. When using a registered test user, the in-app purchases work flawlessly. However, when attempting the same process with an external user, I consistently encounter an 'item not available' error.

I've verified that the in-app products are active and properly configured in the Google Play Console. Is there something specific I might be missing regarding in-app purchase configurations for external users? Has anyone experienced a similar issue or could provide guidance on how to resolve this discrepancy between test users and external users? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be immensely appreciated.